# Python Leetcode 3: Time limit exceeded

Tags: python, algorithm

I am solving LeetCode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/:

> Given a string `s`, find the length of the **longest substring** without repeating characters.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> - `0 <= s.length <= 5 * 104`
> - `s` consists of English letters, digits, symbols and spaces.

If used this sliding window algorithm:

```py
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(str):
    # define base case
    if (len(str) < 2): return len(str)

    # define pointers and frequency counter
    left = 0
    right = 0
    freqCounter = {} # used to store the character count
    maxLen = 0

    while (right < len(str)):
        # adds the character count into the frequency counter dictionary
        if (str[right] not in freqCounter):
            freqCounter[str[right]] = 1
        else:
            freqCounter[str[right]] += 1
            # print (freqCounter)
        # runs the while loop if we have a key-value with value greater than 1. 
        # this means that there are repeated characters in the substring. 
        # we want to move the left pointer by 1 until that value decreases to 1 again. E.g., {'a':2,'b':1,'c':1} to {'a':1,'b':1,'c':1}
        while (len(freqCounter) != right-left+1):
        # while (freqCounter[str[right]] > 1): ## Time Limit Exceeded Error
            print(len(freqCounter), freqCounter)
            freqCounter[str[left]] -= 1
            # remove the key-value if value is 0
            if (freqCounter[str[left]] == 0):
                del freqCounter[str[left]]
            left += 1
        
        maxLen = max(maxLen, right-left+1)
        # print(freqCounter, maxLen)
        right += 1
    
    return maxLen

print(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb")) # 3 'abc'
```

I got the error "Time Limit Exceeded" when I submitted with this while loop:

```
while (freqCounter[str[right]] > 1):
```

instead of

```
while (len(freqCounter) != right-left+1):
```

I thought the first is accessing an element in a dictionary, which has a time complexity of O(1). Not sure why this would be significantly slower than the second version. This seems to mean my approach is not optimal in either case. I thought *sliding window* would be the most efficient algorithm; did I implement it wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249918/discussion-on-question-by-jessica-python-leetcode-3-time-limit-exceeded).

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm running time is close to the timeout limit for some tests -- I even got the time-out with the version `len(freqCounter)`. The difference between the two conditions you have tried cannot be that much different, so I would look into more drastic ways to improve the efficiency of the algorithm:

- Instead of counting the frequency of letters, you could store the *index* of where you last found the character. This allows you to update `left` in one go, avoiding a second loop where you had to decrease frequencies at each unit step.
- Performing a `del` is really not necessary.
- You can also use some more pythonic looping, like with `enumerate`

Here is the update of your code applying those ideas (the first one is the most important one):

```
class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        lastpos = {}
        left = 0
        maxLen = 0

        for right, ch in enumerate(s):
            if lastpos.setdefault(ch, -1) >= left:
                left = lastpos[ch] + 1
            else:
                maxLen = max(maxLen, right - left + 1)
            lastpos[ch] = right
        return maxLen
```

Another boost can be achieved when you work with ASCII codes instead of characters, as then you can use a list instead of a dictionary. As the code challenge guarantees the characters are from a small set of basic characters, we don't need to take other character codes into consideration:

```
class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        lastpos = [-1] * 128
        left = 0
        maxLen = 0

        for right, asc in enumerate(map(ord, s)):
            if lastpos[asc] >= left:
                left = lastpos[asc] + 1
            else:
                maxLen = max(maxLen, right - left + 1)
            lastpos[asc] = right
        return maxLen
```

When submitting this, it scored very well in terms of running time.